# Implementation of linear regression in Python

Tags: python, performance, machine-learning, vectorization

I wrote an implementation for multivariate linear regression in Python, for data in this link: http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Advertising.csv

My main focus is to avoid loops as much as possible by using vectorization, and letting `numpy`'s functions do all the work.

How can I improve my code for performance and enhanced vectorization?

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# read data matrix
data = np.genfromtxt('Advertising.csv', delimiter=',',dtype=float, skiprows=1)
m, n = data.shape

X = data[:, 0:n-1]
Y = data[:, n-1].reshape((m, 1))

# add unity vector column with size m to the X matrix, to account for theta_0
ones = np.ones((m, 1))
X = np.hstack((ones, X))

iterations = 500        # gradient descent iterations count
alpha = 0.01            # learning rate

theta = np.random.rand(n, 1)

def plotData():
    # get rid of X_0 constants column
    features = X[:, 1: n]
    plt.figure(1)

    plt.subplot(131)
    plt.plot(features[:, 0], Y, 'bo')
    plt.title('Ad dollars spent on TV')
    plt.ylabel('Sales')

    plt.subplot(132)
    plt.plot(features[:, 1], Y, 'ro')
    plt.title('Ad dollars spent on Radio')
    plt.ylabel('Sales')

    plt.subplot(133)
    plt.plot(features[:, 2], Y, 'yo')
    plt.title('Ad dollars spent on Newspaper')
    plt.ylabel('Sales')

    plt.show()

def computeCost():
    hypothesis = np.dot(X, theta);
    delta = np.dot((hypothesis - Y).transpose(), (hypothesis - Y))
    return (1 / m) * delta

# normalizeFeatures: scale-normalize all features to speed up gradient descent convergence
def normalizeFeatures():
    # 1) generate Average vector mu, contains the average of each feature in the X matrix
    # 2) generate Std. deviation vector sigma, contains the std. dev. of each feature in the X matrix
    # 3) subtract average value and divide by the standard deviation, for each feature column
    mu = np.ones((1, n))
    sigma = np.ones((1, n))

    # range() starts from 1 not 0, to skip the first all-ones constants column in the features matrix
    for i in range(1,n):
        mu[0][i] = np.mean(X[:, i])
        sigma[0][i] = np.std(X[:, i])
        X[:, i] = (X[:, i] - mu[0][i]) / sigma[0][i]

    return mu, sigma;

# gradientDescent() calculates hypothesis equation coefficients using gradient descent algorithm
def gradientDescent(theta):
    # vector to keep track of progression of cost function with each iteration
    J_history = np.ones((iterations, 1))

    for i in range(iterations):
        delta = np.dot((np.dot(X,theta) - Y).transpose(), X).transpose()
        theta -= (alpha/m) * delta
        J_history[i, 0] = computeCost()

    plt.plot(np.linspace(0, iterations, iterations), J_history)
    plt.title('Cost function against number of iterations')
    plt.xlabel('Number of iterations')
    plt.ylabel('Cost function J(theta)')
    plt.show()
    return

# normalEquation() calculates hypothesis equation coefficients analytically
def normalEquation():
    A = np.linalg.pinv(np.dot(X.transpose(), X))
    B = np.dot(X.transpose(), Y)
    theta = np.dot(A, B)

    return theta

def predict(x_vector, mu, sigma):
    # scale feature vector
    for i in range(1, n):
        x_vector[0][i] = (x_vector[0,i]- mu[0][i]) / sigma[0][i]

    return np.dot(x_vector, theta)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plotData()
    mu, sigma = normalizeFeatures()
    gradientDescent(theta)
    print('Hypothesis coefficients from gradient descent:\n {}'.format(theta))
    print('Hypothesis coefficients from normal equation:\n {}'.format(normalEquation()))

    prediction_vector = np.array([1, 40, 40, 48]).reshape(1,4)
    print('Prediction for values [1, 40, 40, 48] is {}'.format(predict(prediction_vector, mu, sigma)))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just reviewing `normalizeFeatures`.

1. Instead of a comment explaining what the function does, write a docstring. (Docstrings are available from the interactive interpreter via the [`help`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help) function.)
2. The function operates on the global variable `X`. This makes the function inflexible (you can't use it for anything other than modifying the particular variable `X`), and hard to test. It would be better if the function received the array as an argument, so that it could be used on any array:

   ```
   def normalize_features(a):
       """Given array a with shape (m, n), update it so that each column
       (except column 0) has mean 0 and standard deviation 1. Return
       arrays mu, sigma with shape (1, n) where mu[0,i] is the original
       mean of a[:,i] and sigma[0,i] is the original standard deviation
       of a[:,i].

       """
   ```
3. This complicated specification can be simplified. First, we can avoid the "(except column 0)" bit and let the caller pass `X[:,1:]` if they want to leave column 0 alone. Second, we can return `mu` and `sigma` with shape `(n,)` instead of `(1, n)` and let the caller reshape if necessary (which it probably isn't).

   ```
   def normalize_features(a):
       """Given array a with shape (m, n), update it so that each column has
       mean 0 and standard deviation 1. Return arrays mu, sigma giving
       the original mean and standard deviation of each column of a.

       """
   ```
4. The loop over the columns is unnecessary because [`numpy.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) and [`numpy.std`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) take an `axis` argument. So the body of the function can be:

   ```
   mu = a.mean(axis=0)
   sigma = a.std(axis=0)
   a[...] = (a - mu) / sigma
   return mu, sigma
   ```
5. It might be better not to update the array `X`, but to compute a new array containing the normalized data (this uses twice the memory, but that's only a concern if `X` is really big). If you did this, then you wouldn't need to remember the original mean and standard deviation (because you still have the original data) and so the normalization becomes a one-liner:

   ```
   def normalize_features(a):
       """Return copy of a with each column normalized so that it has mean 0
       and standard deviation 1.

       """
       return (a - a.mean(axis=0)) / a.std(axis=0)
   ```
6. Consider using [`scipy.stats.zscore`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html) instead of writing your own.

Comment: Is `a[...]` actual NumPy syntax or did you omit something?

Comment: @mkrieger1: It is actual NumPy syntax. See the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).